# How to fix the macro expansion problem in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

How to fix the macro expansion issue below ?

```
#define GET_VAL                        3,2
#define ADD_VAL(val0, val1)            ((val0) + (val1))

void foo()
{
    int res = ADD_VAL(GET_VAL);
}
```

The macro is getting expanded as below and resulting in an error. I am using MSVC 2019

```
res = 3,2 + ;
```

I even tried using a helper macro as below, but still getting the same error.

```
#define GET_VAL                  3,2
#define ADD_VAL1(val0, val1)     (val0 + val1)
#define ADD_VAL(val)             ADD_VAL1(val)
```

Expecting expansion:
ADD_VAL(GET_VAL); --> ADD_VAL(3, 2); --> 3 + 2

Comment: Your question is inconsistent. The first example should result in `ptr` appearing in the expansion. Your second example should produce the expansion you expect, what error did you get?

Comment: As @DanBonachea said, your second example should normally work. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de420577039f7e7b

Comment: Can you elaborate on your goals? The C preprocessor can be abused in horrible ways for [code obfuscation](https://www.ioccc.org/years.html#2020) but why else?

Comment: `I even tried using a helper macro as below, but still getting the same error.` What error? `Expecting expansion: ADD_VAL(GET_VAL); --> ADD_VAL(3, 2); --> 3 + 2` And I am also expecting this expansion with another pass, this is what should happen.

Answer (score 2):

By default msvc doesn't use a standard confirming preprocessor implementation, make sure to enable it with  /Zc:preprocessor

Macros fully expand their arguments in isolation before pasting them into the replacement text, but the resulting tokens aren't separated into a new argument list. They way to fix your behavior is to create an intermediate macro that expands the arguments, and passes the expanded arguments to your macro:

```
#define GET_VAL 1,2
#define ADD_VAL(...) ADD_VAL_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ADD_VAL_(a,b) ((a)+(b))
ADD_VAL(GET_VAL) // should work now
```

Another option is to write a fx macro that evaluates arguments and applies a function to them:

```
#define FX(f,...) f(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ADD_VAL(a,b) ((a)+(b))
FX(ADD_VAL,GET_VAL) // should work now
```

Answer (score -1):

[C preprocessor can be abused in horrible ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75168127/how-to-fix-the-macro-expansion-problem-in-c#comment132645578_75168127)

```
#define GET_VAL                3,2
// #define ADD_VAL(val0, val1)    ((val0) + (val1))
#define ADD_VAL(val)       ((int [2]){val}[0] + (int [2]){val}[1])

int main() {
  printf("%d\n",ADD_VAL(GET_VAL));
}
```

Output

```
5
```